# why the output is 1 2 3 13 ,whats the logic behind?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

What would be the output? can anyone explain the output. Can anyone explain how functions are invoked?

```js
var x = 0;

function hn() {
  x++;
  console.log(x);

  return (function hn() {

    x += 10;

    console.log(x);
  })
}

hn(hn())(hn());
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of evaluation can be shown by adding a message.

1. `hn("A")` is evaluated, prints "A: 1" and return a function (let's call it F1) that increments x by 10 and display its value.
2. `hn(F1)` is then evaluated. It increments x and prints: "function hn(msg2) {

   x += 10;

   console.log(msg2 + ": "+ x);
   }: 2" => the message is the function F1 here (a bit strange, ok)
   Note that F1 is not invoked, only it's string representation is used.
   It returns a function (let's call it F2) that increments x by 10 and display its value.
3. `hn("B")` is evaluated, prints "B: 3" and return a function (let's call it F3) that increments x by 10 and display its value.
4. `F2(F3)` is evaluated, it increments x by 10 and prints "function hn(msg2) {

   x += 10;

   console.log(msg2 + ": "+ x);
   }: 13" => the message is the function F3 here (a bit strange, ok)
   Note that F3 is not invoked, only it's string representation is used.
   It returns a function (let's call it F4) that increments x by 10 and display its value.

Note that some functions are created but never called (F1, F3, F5).

```js
var x = 0;

function hn(msg) {
  x++;
  console.log(msg + ": "+ x);

  return (function hn(msg2) {

    x += 10;

    console.log(msg2 + ": "+ x);
  })
}

hn(hn("A"))(hn("B"));
```